# time.Location() returns as "Local" even if /etc/localtime is correct

Tags: go, time, timezone

I want to retrieve timezone location of my system

```
t = time.Now()
tzLoc = t.Location().String()
```

tzLoc is returned as `"Local"`.

I have checked the `time` package source code. As per the source-code, if `TZ` is not set, then `/etc/localtime` is referred.

`TZ` environment variable is not set, and following is the `/etc/localtime` on my system

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 38 Jan 16 06:33 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York
```

Ideally, `time` package should return `America/New_York`, but still it is returning as `Local`

What should I do to get timezone location as `America/New_York` ?

Answer (score 0):

Golang behavior is correct, after changing `TZ` environment variable you should be able to see the result you are expecting. I have run it inside the Golang docker container and it prints out `America/Los_Angeles`. In your terminal please redefine your timezone like example below:

```
 ~$: export TZ=America/Los_Angeles
```

This is also a Docker implementation:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.13.8-alpine3.11

RUN apk update

ENV GO111MODULE=on

WORKDIR /app

ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
```

you could build the dockerfile and run it as per followings:

```
~$: docker build -t stackquestion:1.0 .
~$: docker run --rm -it stackquestion:1.0 sh
```

timezone.go

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tzLoc := time.Now().Location().String()
    fmt.Println(tzLoc)

}
```

and when you run the code, you should get:

```
/app # go run timezone.go 
America/Los_Angeles
```

Comment: If TZ is set, then golang itself will give the correct result, won't it ? What if TZ is not set ??

Comment: If TZ is not set, consider setting it or reading the symlink from `/etc/localtime`.

Comment: There seems like a miss-understanding, Golang uses `/etc/localtime` when `TZ` is not set, even if you copy `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York` to `/etc/localtime`, and even set `/etc/timezone` to `America/New_York` you will still get `Local` unless `TZ` is defined. Please read official docs at: https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo.go Line 67